# Modifying the Hakyll example site

Tags: haskell, web, blogs, hakyll

I wish to modify the following code so that, rather than producing links to the latest three posts on the site, it reproduces the body of the posts in their entirely, like in a traditional blog. I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what's going on below, and what the necessary changes would be.

```
match "index.html" $ do
    route idRoute
    compile $ do
        let indexCtx = field "posts" $ \_ ->
                            postList $ fmap (take 3) . recentFirst

        getResourceBody
            >>= applyAsTemplate indexCtx
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" postCtx
            >>= relativizeUrls
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not entirely trivial. A first step is introducing [snapshots](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/05-snapshots-feeds.html).

As explained in the tutorial, this ensures you can include the blogposts on your index *without* having the templates applied to the HTML first. So you'll get something like:

```
match "posts/*" $ do
    route $ setExtension "html"
    compile $ pandocCompiler
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/post.html"    postCtx
        >>= saveSnapshot "content"
        >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" postCtx
        >>= relativizeUrls
```

Now, in order to display the posts on the index page, you will be able to use the entire `$body$` of the posts. In order to do this, you'll just have to update `templates/post-item.html` into something like:

```
<div>
    <a href="$url$"><h2>$title$</h2></a>
    $body$
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this seems to reproduce all the headers in addition to the content of each post.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a bit old but since it does not seem to be resolved here is how I went about it.

First save a snapshot as described by @jaspervdj:

```
match "posts/*" $ do
  route $ setExtension "html"
  compile $ pandocCompiler
    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/post.html"  postCtx
    >>= saveSnapshot "content"
    >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" postCtx
    >>= relativizeUrls
```

Then for `index.html` load all the post snapshots with `loadAllSnapshots`:

```
match "index.html" $ do
  route idRoute
  compile $ do
    posts <- recentFirst =<< loadAllSnapshots "posts/*" "content"
    let indexCtx = listField "posts" postCtx (return posts) `mappend`
                   defaultContext
```

Since the snapshot was taken before applying `default` template, the value of `$body$` within `$for(posts)$` will be just the content of each post template without the default template applied.